# Аналог sleep(5) на PHP

Tags: php, сервер

Как сказать серверу на `PHP` чтобы он прервал вою работу н а `t` секунд, а затем продолжил снова. По возможности сильно не нагружая сервер.

Comment: Вы не поверите, аналог `sleep(5)` на php - `sleep(5)` =)

Comment: Я уже было собирался через while делать..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отсрочка выполнение [sleep()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.sleep.html). Есть еще похожая функция [usleep()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.usleep.html) и функция [set_time_limit()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.set-time-limit.html), которая ограничивает время выполнения. Так что "Аналог sleep(5) на PHP" - это и есть sleep ))

Answer (score 1):

Аналог? Это он и есть )) Необязательно же его в начале кода писать

```
sleep(10); // засыпаем на 10 сек.
// дальше код
```

Comment: @johniek_comp, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.